# Open custom inbound firewall ports e.g. 8077 by any way using java in azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, windows-firewall

I am launching one windows instance in Azure(Microsoft) using Java and trying to open few inbound ports like 445, 8077 for my work.
I have also tried using Security groups port opening but it is only opening the inbound ports at security group level, not at the system level.
Provide me some solution so that I can open either before launch itself or after launch is also fine. I have done the same thing in AWS as asked in below URL:
[Open some custom inbound ports e.g. 8077 by using 80 or 3389](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653202/open-some-custom-inbound-ports-e-g-8077-by-using-80-or-3389)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is right,you use a Windows VM in Azure(Iaas service). It is same with AWS instance, you could use Power Shell to open port 8077 on Windows Firewall.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 8077" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8077
```

On Azure VM, you also need open port on [Azure NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).
[image]

Update:

If you want to use Azure java SDK to do this, you could use this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/java-sdk-manage-virtual-machines).

I modify the example to add Custom Script Extension like below:

```
        windowsVM.update()
            .defineNewExtension("shuitest")
            .withPublisher("Microsoft.Compute")
            .withType("CustomScriptExtension")
            .withVersion("1.9")
            .withMinorVersionAutoUpgrade()
            .withPublicSetting("commandToExecute", "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"Open Port 8077\" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8077")
            .attach()
        .apply();
```

You could check my [code](https://gist.github.com/Walter-Shui/73a827fb81eb15788c60a11bb5dc097e) on Github.

Comment: If you using Azure App service(Paas service), it only allows port 80, 444. But based on my understanding, you using Azure VM, it is seem with local  Windows instance, you could easily open port on Windows Firewall.

Comment: Netsh is not directly related with powershell.

Comment: @eckes Yes, `netsh` could execute in Power Shell or cmd console.

Comment: @shengbao You are correct on this point but in AWS they are giving some API option to add user data before launching the system. If that is there then it would be fine. 
Otherwise, I need to run the above PowerShell command using Java on that machine from my local machine

Comment: @Ankit4mjis In Azure VM, if you want to access a java service from port 8077. You need open port on Windows Firewall and Azure NSG. Open port on Windows firewall, it seems with AWS. Using ` 
If my understanding is right,you use a Windows VM in Azure(Iaas service). It is same with AWS instance, you could use Power Shell to open port 8077 on Windows Firewall.

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 8077" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8077`

Comment: You need open port on Azure NSG, it is different from AWS. I show a screeshot how to do it.

Comment: I don't want to access a Java service from 8077. But I need to open 8077 for my other task to be accomplished using Java only.  Or could you suggest something like how to run the above Powershell command remotely using Java? 
I know how to do it using Java on the local system.

Comment: Hi, could you access your VM and do it inside it?

Comment: If my understanding is right, you want to open port 8077 on Azure VM firewall with java?

Comment: If my understanding is right, you could use Azure VM script extension to do this, using extension, you could execute some cmdlet as user aministrator.

Comment: https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineExtension.html

Comment: Based on my understanding, Azure VM custom script extension is similar with AWS userdata. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, if you need open port on Azure NSG by using java SDK? It is easily for you to do this.

Comment: Let me give a try and then will let you know about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161099/discussion-between-ankit4mjis-and-shengbao-shui-msft).

Answer (score 1):

No, we don’t allow to open custom port on PaaS. You have to move to Azure VM to be able to open custom ports.